# Need direction in creating a voice chat application

Tags: apache-flex, flash, chat, voip, voice

I want to create a voice chat application as a part of a project. However, i am totally lacking direction regarding the programming language to use, the technologies involved.

Can somebody please guide me as to how i should proceed ?

Here are the features that i require :

- user to user voice chat
- ability to chat in conference (more than 2 users)

How do i connect one user to another ? How to handle voice transmission ? How to effectively route packets in a conference ?

I'm thinking the most probably langauge to develop this in would be Flash. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to research:

- APIs for this were added to AIR 2.0  ( http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_SimpleAudioRecorder___Microphone_Access_API_AIR_2_-16746.html  ).  I believe you can combine them with socket classes for Peer to Peer communication to create a Skype like chat app.
- Look into a tool like Ribbit ( http://developer.ribbit.com/ )
- Look into using a server side software to handle audio.  Red5 is a popular open source one. ( http://red5.org/ ).  Flash Media Server is an Adobe Option ( http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/ )

Answer (score 0):

To get a good video chat, you should use UDP P2P communication. There is only few solutions ready for that, but [Adobe Stratus 2](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/) is one.