# Video chat application : Which technology to choose?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, video-streaming, chat

I have to undertake a project which is to make a video chat application.

The video has to be streamed from one location and can be viewed by multiple people spread out over the globe. Performance is really an issue and a delay of more than 2-3 seconds is unacceptable.

From what i gather, this can be done in Flex and also in JAVA. Any performance issues and caveats with a particular approach ? I would really like the pros to comment on this and guide me through. Will be very very helpful.

Are there any open source libraries available for video recording in flash / JAVA which i can integrate into my app and customize according to my needs ?

Comment: Hi! have you thought of the policy which u will be using to stream the video?The question is more generic in the term of how exactly will you be transmitting ur video to multiple people in an optimal way? of course you can choose brute force method and send a packet by your self to each and every one who requests.But soon u'll be depleted of bandwidth.So u'll hv to use certain heuristic to stream the video(consider u hv to transmit to million of ppl)?So hv u ponder over these questions.So more than implemenation ur policy matters which will decide quality of ur application.Mawia

Comment: This is almost the same question as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852430/need-direction-in-creating-a-voice-chat-application

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using a set of extensions to XMPP ( a la Google Talk). 
Gtalk uses [Jingle](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/index.html) and is open-sourced.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [RED5](http://osflash.org/red5). It is open source and uses Flex, Java, Springframework.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need recording? Otherwise, I'd just stick with [P2P](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/).